# Wordpress show theme version to user dynamically

Tags: php, database, wordpress, themes

I have two themes "axijas" and "axijas v2". I want to show first user version 1, second user version 2, third user version 1 etc.

I write a code, that look in database, which version was showed last, change the value and show the other version. Of course, I store this version in session, beause I want, if user has selected version 2, next few click he/she should see only version 2.

Problem is, that I'm using function "switch_theme()" and it's not working as I expected. It change theme completly for everybody, sometimes I have even problem to switch it manually in dashboard.

How can I have activated version1, and it will be ignored, and only theme will be included by the rule? Is there any hook for it or something? I only want, that if user click on page, call function, that control if he has set session and if not, get version for show in database, change value and include theme folder for that user.

Thank you very much for your help

P.S.:hope you understand my bad english

Comment: What about using plugin for that? https://wordpress.org/plugins/mdc-theme-switcher/

Comment: At first - I don't want user can do that on his own, it should be automatically and second - every plugin uses changing url to something like /?theme=alternative_theme .. I don't want this